# In Adacore's GPR file, how can I set the compiler include search paths for C++

Tags: gnat, gprbuild

I have some C++ code that I need to compile using Adacore GNAT Programming Studio.

One file (**SomeHeader.h**) is in a Common directory (**../../Common/**) relative to my GPR file.

Our convention for C++ include directives is to use

```
#include "Common/SomeHeader.h"
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get GprBuild to find "Common/SomeHeader.h"
I followed the instructions here at [AdaGem 108](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-108-gprbuild-and-configuration-files-part-2) with modifications for C++

```
for Include_Switches ("c++") use ("-I ../../");
```

and

```
for Include_Path ("c++") use "../..";
```

None of this seems to work for me during **gprbuild** and frustratingly I can't seem to get at the backend command that **gprbuild** is using even after turning the build verbosity up.

I see some temp files in the build messages but they get deleted before I can access them.

I am using Adacore GPS 17.1 on Windows 10  i686-pc-mingw32, GNAT Pro 17.1.

Does anyone know how to get include search paths working in Adacore's **Gprbuild**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to use `gprbuild` for compiling C++ source text yet, but I suppose it works more or less like with Ada, where you add the relevant directories to the `Source_Dirs` attribute:

```
project Cookie is
   for Languages use ("C++");

   for Source_Dirs use (".",
                        "../..");

   [...]
end Cookie;
```

Comment: The problem is that the Common files are compiled in a separate GPR file that I am withing into this one so I don't want them to be in this one too because I will get duplicate symbols at link time.  Maybe I can isolate the header files from the cpp files though and try what you suggested.  I'm still not sure if the **Common/SomeHeader.h** will work though.  I will try tomorrow morning.

Comment: Then you may need to mark the GPR file for the common files as a `library project`.

Comment: Does the common files GPR file list the directory containing "SomeHeader.h" in `Source_Dirs`?  If that's the case, the solution may be to remove "Common/" from the `include` directive in the C++ source file.

Comment: Yes the common files GPR has the directory containing SomeHeader.h.

Comment: I marked this as the answer since the directory at the top level `../..` does not contain any source files.  I was able to add that as a source dir in my GPR file even though it does not cause any files to be added to the project.  This gives me the ability to have `#include "Common/SomeHeader.h"` in my files

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jacob

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use relative paths, and you are dead set on using the `-I` flag, be aware that the current directory at the time you compile your c++ code it is set to the obj directory configured for grp.

So if the directory you want to include is located at `C:\Foo\Bar\src\include\` and your grp obj directory is at `C:\Foo\Bar\env\gpr\obj` then your relative path will need to use `-I..\..\..\src\include`

Comment: Yes, the level of indirection is one more than for the Source_Dirs since the -I is invoked from the obj dir